# PhoneGap FileTransfer upload always fires successCallback

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 1.4.1 to upload images taken with the camera on the iPhone.  The happy path works and I can upload images successfully using the FileTransfer object's upload function.

However, if I simulate an error by changing the upload URL to point to a 404 or cause the request to 500, the successCallback still fires.

I've looked into the PhoneGap guts and found that the responseCode set here is always null even though I can see in my server logs that it is 404 or 500.  null status codes seem to be interpreted as success.

```
FileTransfer.prototype._castUploadResult = function(pluginResult) {
    var result = new FileUploadResult();
    result.bytesSent = pluginResult.message.bytesSent;
    result.responseCode = pluginResult.message.responseCode;
    result.response = decodeURIComponent(pluginResult.message.response);
    pluginResult.message = result;
    return pluginResult;
}
```

Unfortunately I don't see anything else in the code to help me debug this further.

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?